# Use of "name" property in form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've noticed form elements also include a `name` parameter in HTML, as such:

`<input type="button" id="btnID" name="btnNAME" value="click me">`

I dont really understand the use of `name`. In the following code snippet, I just change the color of btn to red, via its `id`. What is the purpose of `name` attribute? (an example would be nice)

```css
#btnID {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnID" name="btnNAME" value="click me">
```

Comment: name is basically holds the value of the input or select field. so If you submit a form and you didn't mention the name attribute you will not get the field value in request data.

Comment: which one praveen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `name` attribute isn't really necessary when you are not sending data through it. The `id` of the form input element can fulfill the purpose of hooking the element with JavaScript and CSS.

The name attribute is used in the `HTTP` request sent by your browser to the server as a variable name associated with the data contained in the `value` attribute.

Here I'm taking example of extracting data with php in a login form. If you don't know php you wouldn't probably know `$_POST` and `$_GET`. For now just know that they are used to extract data sent with this `HTTP` request.

```
<form action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="user" value="kittyCat">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="querty123">
</form>
```

Now in `login.php` file you can extract the data like this:

```
$userName = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

here  `user` points to the fist input so  `$username` will be equal to the `value` of that input, which is `"kittyCat"`. similarly `$password` will be equal to `"qwerty123"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use name attributes for form controls (such as input and select'), as that's the identifier used in the POST or GET call that happens on form submission.

Answer (score -1):

The NAME attribute is used for grabbing a value of an element via PHP, e.g.:

HTML w/ PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'):
    $fn = $_POST['first_name'];
    echo $fn; // prints "Santa" on the page

    //or we can create something:

    ?><p><?php echo $fn; ?></p><?php // creates a p element w/ santa inside

endif;
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="Santa" />
<input type="submit" value="Do Something" />
</form>
```

Once the HTML form is submitted, the little block of php code will run.

Just so you know, you can style an element using CSS by grabbing an element by name, e.g.:

HTML

```
<input name="something" type="text" />
```

CSS

```
input[name="something"] { color: red; }
```